# How to modify the starting boundary of an ext4 partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, ext4, parted

There are 4 partitions on the disk.

```
parted /dev/sda --script -- print
...
1 1049KB 50.0GB ... ext4
2 50GB   82GB   ... linux-swap
3 82GB   100GB  ... ext4
4 100GB  1000GB ... ext4
```

My goal is to modify the starting position of 4, then expand 3, at the same time without losing data. I know using gparted it would be quite easy but it is within an automatic script and cannot launch UI.

After some search, it seems to use "cfdisk" to delete and create new partition, then do "resize2fs". But the trick is, if I modify the starting position of a partition, the "ext4" property is gone and "resize2fs" complain unknown super-block.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To me, definitely risky while a system is mounted.

If you can take a downtime, I would suggest using gparted.  Boots up into a mini kernel and lets you resize partitions.

Still a bit risky, so of course make sure you have good backups!